Проблема с развёртыванем Taiga
В локальной сети, на машине развернул тайгу (https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-docker), надо теперь выбросить доступ в общую сеть. Пробросил порты (с локалки на машину и с машины саму на себя) 9000 и 9001(именно на них работает тайга) на машину с глобальным айпишником(будем считать этот ip 777.777.777.777 и ssh там слушает порт 777):
local@machine ~> ssh -f -N -g -R 7001:localhost:9001 global@777.777.777.777 -p 777 sleep 1
global@machine ~> ssh -f -N -g -L 9000:localhost:7000 global@127.0.0.1 -p 777 sleep 1


теперь отлично, мобильное приложение(https://github.com/EugeneTheDev/TaigaMobile) по глобальному адресу и порту 9000
Но если заходить с удаленного браузера по http://777.777.777.777:9000/
то выходит ошибка: "Taiga
Something happened and the Taiga has captured the error to be able to work on it."

Проблема в итоге такая : На всех машинах, кроме localhost-a (даже в локальной сети если обращаться, по адресу в локальной сети) , тайга в браузере выдает такую ошибку, как выше.
Нажал F12 начал копать, понял, что дело в запросах:
для локалхоста они такие:

для остальных такие:

Кто с таким сталкивался или знает как копать чтобы решить проблему, буду очень благодарен. Всем успехов!!!
